# Is there a correct mathematical term for the inverse of the slope?

Tags: slope

Linear graphs all have a slope that can be calculated by deviding the progress on the y-axis by the progress on the x-axis. Is there a correct term to refer to the inverse of the slope, that means the progress on the x-axis devided by the progress on the y-axis.

Comment: No special term.  That is "the reciprocal of the slope".  It is also the slope of the (local) inverse function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of such a term. However, in some cases, the inverse of the slope will just be the slope of its inverse function.